# How can I filter in Firebase realtime database and get to show specific content in Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with Angular and Firebase realtime database. I have a collection of photos in my database called "imageDetail" in which each item has: -category - caption - imageUrl

I'm trying to filter my items according to their category and get to show the result in separate components. I managed to get the correct result in the console, but my problem is that I can't have the results to shows in my component.

In this example I'm trying to filter in my collection the category "nature", I have tried a lot of different ways but I either get all the photos in my collection or no photos at all.

Here's the function I have in my Image Service:

```
  getImageByCategory(category: string) {

    const dbRef = this.firebaseDB.database.ref('imageDetail');

    return dbRef.orderByChild("category").equalTo(category).on("child_added", snap => {
      console.log(snap.val());  // -> this shows me what I want
    });

  }
```

And here's my Nature component where I intend to show ONLY the photos of the category "nature":

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ImageService } from '../services/image.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nature',
  templateUrl: './nature.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nature.component.css']
})
export class NatureComponent implements OnInit {

  naturePhotos: any[];

  constructor(private imageService: ImageService) {
    this.naturePhotos = [];
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    let listaPhoto = this.imageService.getImageByCategory("nature");
    listaPhoto.snapshotChanges().subscribe(
      list => {
        this.naturePhotos = list.map(item => { return item.payload.val() });
      });

  }

}
```

I also get this error message "Property 'snapshotChanges' does not exist on type '(a: DataSnapshot, b?: string) => any'."

I'm not too sure what's going wrong, can anybody help me figure out how to separate each category in my collection and get them to show in several different components?

Answer (score 0):

Method `on(...)` doesn't return the result, it return the callback that you provided
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on

You should create an Observable instead that emit your result:

```js
getImageByCategory(category: string) {
  const dbRef = this.firebaseDB.database.ref('imageDetail');
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    const callback = dbRef.orderByChild("category")
      .equalTo(category)
      .on('child_added', snap => {
        observer.next(snap.val());
      }, error => observer.error(error));
    // Return a function with teardown logic that run when you unsubscribe
    return () => dbRef.off('child_added', callback);
  });
}
```

Note that I am not familiar with Firebase Database, so this may not be the best way.

In your component, you can use it in a couple of way.

#### With async pipe (simpler):

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
<div class="container" *ngFor="let photo of photos$ | async">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="{{photo.imageURL}}" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
  photos$!: Observable<Photo[]>;

  constructor(
    private imageService: ImageService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.photos$ = this.imageService.getImageByCategory('nature');
  }
}
```

#### By subscribing:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
<div class="container" *ngFor="let photo of photos">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="{{photo.imageURL}}" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  photos: Photo[] = [];
  private subscription!: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private imageService: ImageService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.photos = this.imageService.getImageByCategory('nature')
      .subscribe(photos => this.photos = photos);
      // Or you can do: .subscribe(photos => this.photos.push(...photos);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // This is important to prevent memory leak
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately I still can't manage to have it print anything in my html, it's still the same result (either printing no image at all or all the images in my collection). I'm probably doing something wrong though, any idea how I should call this function in my component?

Comment: I'm not sure about the filter, what do you get if you console.log snap.val()? In your component you either use the async pipe or subscribe to the result of getImageByCategory.

Comment: When I console.log snap.val() I get this the correct objects so your function worked out great! 

But here's what I have in nature.ts component:

``` 

    this.imageService.getImageByCategory("nature").subscribe(
      list => {
        this.naturePhotos.push(list)
      });
``` 

And in my nature.html, this: 

```
    <div class="container" *ngFor="let photo of naturePhotos">

        <div class="photo">
            <img src="{{photo.imageURL | async}}" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

```

Somehow nothing prints out on the screen and I can't understand why...

Comment: I updated the answer with example from your code. I think the problem is you're using the async pipe on a string and you push the whole array into `naturePhotos` instead of the elements.

Comment: I tried both but the problem I have is this error I get: Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<photo[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.

What is that type<Photo[]>? I'm not sure I understand it, I should have it declared in my imageService I assume but how? Sorry for the confusion I'm really new to this!

Comment: `type<Photo[]>` is a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html). It looks like you're trying to call subscribe (or using async pipe) on something that is not an Observable. If you could provide a Stackblitz, I could tell you the exact error.